# Proving space is banach

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $$X=\left\{u\in L^1(\mu):\int_\Omega u~ d\mu=0\right\}$$
I want to show $(X,\|\cdot\|_{L^1})$ is banach.

Subspace of normed space is normed space so I just have to show convergence.
Let $u_n$ be Cauchy in $X$. I want to show it has a limit in $X$

$$\|{u_n}\|_{L^1}= \int {\lim_n u_n}~d\mu =\int \lim_n |u_n|~d\mu=\lim_n\int|u_n|d\mu <\infty$$
since the $u_n$ are themselves in $L^1$ so the limit is in $L^1$. How do I show the sequence converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove that $X$ is closed (this follows from the fact that $u\mapsto\int_\Omega u\,\mathrm d\mu$ is continuous) and use the fact that a closed subspace of a complete space is again complete.

Comment: Why is it continuous?

Comment: Because it is linear and$$\lVert u\rVert=1\implies\left\lvert\int_\Omega u\,\mathrm d\mu\right\rvert\leqslant\int_\Omega\lvert u\rvert\,\mathrm d\mu=1.$$

Comment: Bounded linear operator and therefore continuous! Thanks!

Comment: I had already edited my comment when you posted that.

Answer (score 0):

$L^{1}$ is complete, so you only have to show that $X$ is a closed subspace of $L^{1}$. Let $f_n \to f$ in $L^{1}$ norm and suppose $\int f_n d\mu=0$ for all $n$. Then $\int fd\mu=\lim \int f_nd\mu=0$ so $f \in X$.